# Flask - Accept error and flash messsage

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm having a super hard time figuring out how to except an error and return a flash(message).

I'm searching a mongoDB and if a name doesn't exist I get

"'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

as the response to the query. I would like to respond with `flash("Name {} not found!.format(searchName))` so the user knows their search didn't return anything and they can try again.

I've tried doing

```
if searchName == None:
    flash("Name {} not found!.format(searchName))
else:
    do something else
```

Plus a very other variations of that sort. But each time I get the same error if the query doesn't exist. Is there a better way to handle for all or even specific errors and return a desired response? I'm looking to handle specifically Python exception not HTTP errors. Thanks!

Comment: what's the actual code that is throwing the exception ?

Comment: I got it figured out with the answer down below. The issue was with Pymongo query; when it didn't find a result it threw an exception, using try except fixed that.

Comment: The reason I asked is because PyMongo query does not throw an exception when it does not find matching records. The error you have is _generally_ related to Python code accessing a method from an object with `None` value. For example: `variable = None` then you are trying to access `variable[1]`.

Comment: Oh thanks for that knowledge. Then I'm certain the issue was with a blank query be referenced by another portion of the code. So when the query is blank Python was throwing an exception because the value was really None. That's good to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like your MongoDB search is what is throwing the exception.  Try wrapping it in a try ... except and call flash() in the exception handler.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution that caused me so much stress. Sometimes I overthink it.